# Blog page is not displayed as parent of posts in permalink

Tags: wordpress

In my WordPress website, I selected posts page to blog in **Settings -> Reading -> Posts page** and also changed permalink to post name (*mywebsite.com/sample-post*) but blog page did not become the parent of a post page.

Now the path is: *mywebsite.com/post*

But I want to display it as: *mywebsite.com/blog/post*

Answer (score 0):

change the home url and site url as how you want.

For example,

if you want like this mywebsite.com/blog/post then change both url like below,

http://mywebsite.com/blog/